# How to make some parallel https requests using reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I need to make 10 parallel requests to the site from different IPs (at the same time).

I have an array of 10 proxies, I need to make 10 parallel requests to the site using 1 of 10 proxies for each request in order.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let proxy = [
        "https://example.prox:4545",
        "https://example.prox:8080",
        "https://example.prox:80",
        "https://example.prox:90",
        "https://example.prox:9050",
        // ... array of 10 proxy
    ];
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
        .proxy(reqwest::Proxy::all("https://example.prox:4545")?)
        .build()?;

    let url = "http://httpbin.org/ip";

    let resp = client.get(url).send().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`futures::future::join_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html):

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let proxy = [
        "https://example.prox:4545",
        "https://example.prox:8080",
        "https://example.prox:80",
        "https://example.prox:90",
        "https://example.prox:9050",
        // ... array of 10 proxy
    ];
    let responses: Vec<reqwest::Result<reqwest::Response>> =
        futures::future::join_all(proxy.iter().map(|&proxy| async move {
            let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
                .proxy(reqwest::Proxy::all(proxy)?)
                .build()?;

            let url = "http://httpbin.org/ip";

            client.get(url).send().await
        }))
        .await;

    Ok(())
}
```

**Note:** This does not execute the requests *in parallel* but *concurrently*, however this probably does not matter for you.

Comment: But you could easly make those connection happen in parallel if for each one you spawn separate tokio task (and you are on a multithreaded system).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Yes, but there is no reason.